# Explicit differences between <Directory> and <DirectoryMatch> (and other <*Match> directives)

Tags: apache, apache2, configuration

### Preface

I'm very much a neophyte regarding webservers. I'm setting up an Apache2 server and currently poring over the documentation.

I noticed that the [`<Directory>`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directory), [`<Location>`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#location), and [`<Files>`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#files) directives each have a corresponding `<*Match>` directive: [`<DirectoryMatch>`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directorymatch), [`<LocationMatch>`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#locationmatch) and [`<FilesMatch>`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#filesmatch) respectively. The difference on the surface is apparent enough:

- `<*Match>` directives take a regular expression as an argument
- Non-Match directives take a plain string or shell-style glob as their argument.

Curiously, the non-Match directives can **also** be given a regular expression as their argument if it is preceded by a '~'. Thus, the following two lines ought to be identical:

```
# From the Apache2 docs
<Directory ~ "^/www/[0-9]{3}"> ... </Directory>
<DirectoryMatch "^/www/[0-9]{3}"> ... </DirectoryMatch>
```

### Questions

What I'd like to know is whether or not there are any subtle or key differences to be aware of that [Apache's `core` docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directory) do not mention. The `<DirectoryMatch>` section does mention one subtle difference:

> **Compatibility**
>
> **Prior to 2.3.9**, this directive implicitly applied to sub-directories (like `<Directory>`) and could not match the end of line symbol ($). **In 2.3.9 and later**, only directories that match the expression are affected by the enclosed directives.

Beyond that, I would like to know:

- Are there any other differences between the Match and non-Match directives?
- Which directive is more preferable when a regular expression is required?
- Any other information you feel is pertinent?

#### Notes

- `<DirectoryMatch>` and `<Directory "~">` are on the same [merge level](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html#merging)
- While not explicitly mentioned, `<Directory "~">` can use named groups and backreferences, just like `<DirectoryMatch>`.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is in the parameter type allowed:

```
<Directory directory-path> ... </Directory>
```

vs

```
<DirectoryMatch regex> ... </DirectoryMatch>
```

`DirectoryMatch` is a superset, feature wise as you will be able to code any path as a regex. The opposite is not true.

`Directory ~` is probably a late addition. 
Based on a commit found in repository (commit 07b82419b59d1bb7ba8860b86a2d381d5d1090bc on November 1996), this case was added in Apache 1.2

`DirectoryMatch` was then added in Apache 1.3 (commit a318749e61fda612e883a9ea594459a4517166b8 on July 1997) with a richer set of features.

And the documentation updated in that commit clearly said you should favor the match version when using a regex:

```
    &lt;Directory ~ &quot;^/www/.*/[0-9]{3}&quot;&gt;
 </pre>

-would match directories in /www/ that consisted of three numbers.<p>
+would match directories in /www/ that consisted of three numbers. In
+Apache 1.3 and later, it is reccomended to use
+<a href="#directorymatch">&lt;DirectoryMatch&gt;</a> instead.<p>
```

(this "it is recommended to use DirectoryMatch" statement was removed later in a commit on August 1997)

`DirectoryMatch` is still superior because `Directory ~` are handled only after "normal" `Directory` statements, and `DirectoryMatch` allows you to capture data that you can subsequently use.

When you are using a regex, I would favor the `Match` variant as it makes it clearer that you are using a regular expression, and not a specific case of the non match variant. Besides the small differences above, it would however not make a huge difference.

**UPDATE** in fact probably no changes in result since the code does the same:

```
static const char *dirsection(cmd_parms *cmd, void *mconfig, const char *arg)
{

...

    if (!strcmp(cmd->path, "~")) {
        cmd->path = ap_getword_conf(cmd->pool, &arg);
        if (!cmd->path)
            return "<Directory ~ > block must specify a path";
        r = ap_pregcomp(cmd->pool, cmd->path, AP_REG_EXTENDED|USE_ICASE);
        if (!r) {
            return "Regex could not be compiled";
        }
    }
    else if (thiscmd->cmd_data) { /* <DirectoryMatch> */
        r = ap_pregcomp(cmd->pool, cmd->path, AP_REG_EXTENDED|USE_ICASE);
        if (!r) {
            return "Regex could not be compiled";
        }
    }
```

So exact same call to `r = ap_pregcomp(cmd->pool, cmd->path, AP_REG_EXTENDED|USE_ICASE);` in both cases.

Comment: "DirectoryMatch is a superset" - although the OP is specifically comparing `<Directory ~` and `<DirectoryMatch`, not `<Directory`. Until Apache 2.3.9, `<Directory ~` was arguably the superset because it supported the `$` regex anchor, whereas `<DirectoryMatch` did not. (This may have also been why the recommendation to use `DirectoryMatch` was removed in the earlier docs?)

Comment: "`DirectoryMatch` is still superior because `Directory ~` are handled only after "normal" `Directory` statements, and `DirectoryMatch` allows you to capture data that you can subsequently use." - but as noted by the OP, these directives are the same in both these respects.

Comment: I agree that `DirectoryMatch` is easier to read and therefore preferable (over `Directory ~`). Whilst the docs don't explicitly state this, `DirectoryMatch` is used in all recent examples (eg. on the [Config Sections](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html) page) and `Directory ~` never gets a mention. The docs do, however, explicitly state that the similarly named `LocationMatch` and `FilesMatch` are preferable over the corresponding `~` version of these directives.

Comment: @MrWhite `DirectoryMatch` did not support the `$` anchor before Apache 2.3.9? The commits I found are related to Apache 1.2/1.3, so far before.

Comment: Yes, as stated by the OP (from the [2.4 docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directorymatch)), whereas early examples of `<Directory ~` even included the end-of-string anchor. Yes, I see those commits are from 1.2/1.3 - good digging! :) It's also stated in the [Apache 1.3 docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/core.html#directorymatch) when `DirectoryMatch` was introduced. There were also changes in Apache 1.3 (from 1.2) with regards to how the regex containers (ie. `<Directory ~` and the just introduced `<DirectoryMatch`) were merged.

Comment: Thank you for answering. The `dirsection()` snippet and the two commits are great pieces of info! However, "`DirectoryMatch` is still superior because `Directory ~` are handled only after "normal" `Directory` statements ..." is false as of [at least Apache 1.3](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/sections.html), as already mentioned by @MrWhite. Also already mentioned, `Directory "~"` can also use backreferences; however without looking at code, I can't confirm this beyond 2.4. If you would remove or correct those bits I would be happy to upvote for the other helpful information you provided.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any other differences between the Match and non-Match directives?

Not strictly a difference between the two regex versions (`<Directory ~` and `<DirectoryMatch`), but some directives, such as `AllowOverride` and `AllowOverrideList`, are only permitted in a plain (non-regex) `<Directory>` container. So, that excludes both `<Directory ~` and `<DirectoryMatch`.

Reference:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride

> **Only available in `<Directory>` sections**
>   `AllowOverride` is valid only in `<Directory>` sections specified without regular expressions, not in `<Location>`, `<DirectoryMatch>` or `<Files>` sections.